# Can you find Pokemon lower than level 5 in DelugeRPG?

Tags: deluge-rpg

In the internet pokemon game, DelugeRPG, is it possible to get pokemon that are lower that level 5? If so, can you get it using the daily raffle award, RARE++ ?